# Intregrating Rasa Webchat with custom python functions

Tags: python, chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa

I want to give custom responses to the user on the webchat platform based on external python code. Also I want to retrieve all the user responses and process them to construct said custom responses. How do i connect rasa-webchat with my python code?

Whenever the user says something to the chatbot, i want to trigger a function that uses the intent classification results from rasa and also a few other functions to construct custom bot response.

Comment: Have you tried out rasa actions? It has got what you want. 
https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/api/rasa-sdk/#actions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i bumped into [this](https://github.com/cedextech/rasa-chatbot-templates) when i was looking for some Rasa reference. This might help you on crafting your own custom responses.

For integration with webchat, [this](https://forum.rasa.com/t/rasa-webchat-integration/19930)
forum might be useful. The video tutorial will guide you step by step on how to integrate the webchat with your Rasa model.

Have fun exploring !